# How do I fix an error message of "Cannot implicitly convert type Generic.IEnumerable<type>' to 'Generic.List<type>"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, generics

Why do I get this error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

when I build this code:

```
 List<BALHotelList> searchresult=from a in bh
                join b in hr on a.HotelCode equals b.hotelCode
                orderby a.HotelName
                select new BALHotelList
                    {
                       HotelCode= a.HotelCode,
                       ImageURL_Text = a.ImageURL_Text,
                       HotelName = a.HotelName,
                       StarRating = a.StarRating,
                       HotelAddress = a.HotelAddress,
                       Destination = a.Destination,
                       Country = a.Country,
                       HotelInfo = a.HotelInfo,
                       Latitude = a.Latitude,
                       Longitude = a.Longitude,
                       totalPrice = b.totalPrice,
                       totalPriceSpecified = b.totalPriceSpecified,
                       totalSalePrice = b.totalSalePrice,
                       totalSalePriceSpecified = b.totalSalePriceSpecified,
                       rooms = b.rooms

                    };
```

Comment: why not just use `var searchresult = `

Comment: because var scope is limited to that method .

Comment: that matters? then just throw a `.ToList()` on the end of the query

Comment: @rahularyansharma When `var` is used for an anonymous type, the anonymous type can't leave the method. For a "real" type `var` is just syntactic sugar for typing out the full type name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just need to wrap your linq with some parentheses and call .ToList on the result:

```
List<BALHotelList> searchresult= (from a in bh
            join b in hr on a.HotelCode equals b.hotelCode
            orderby a.HotelName
            select new BALHotelList
                {
                   HotelCode= a.HotelCode,
                   ImageURL_Text = a.ImageURL_Text,
                   HotelName = a.HotelName,
                   StarRating = a.StarRating,
                   HotelAddress = a.HotelAddress,
                   Destination = a.Destination,
                   Country = a.Country,
                   HotelInfo = a.HotelInfo,
                   Latitude = a.Latitude,
                   Longitude = a.Longitude,
                   totalPrice = b.totalPrice,
                   totalPriceSpecified = b.totalPriceSpecified,
                   totalSalePrice = b.totalSalePrice,
                   totalSalePriceSpecified = b.totalSalePriceSpecified,
                   rooms = b.rooms

                }).Tolist();
```

Answer (score 4):

The type returned from the LINQ statement is IEnumerable, not a List.

if you really MUST have it as a List then put () around the whole "From a in.... to select new xxx {};) and call ToList() on the result first.

Otherwise do "var searchresult = ...." and you can foreach on your "searchresult" variable still.

Comment: var is limited to scope and i want to use this as globally

Comment: Right, so do what I said where you explicitly call ToList() on the resulting IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list you need to wrap the Linq query in parentheses and call `.ToList()`.